# label frame not stay Properly in `UICollectionViewCell`

Tags: ios, swift, cornerradius

I am developing custom calendar by `UICollectionView`.
I want to show circle backGround of `label` for today's date.

my code inside uitableviewCell:

```
let todayDate = Date().removeTimeStamp()
    self.lblDate.text = "\(String(describing: day))"
    if date == todayDate{
        lblDate.textColor = .white
        lblDate.layer.cornerRadius = lblDate.frame.width/2
        lblDate.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.appOrange.cgColor
    }else if date < todayDate {
        lblDate.textColor = .lightGray
        lblDate.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    }else{
        lblDate.textColor = .black
        lblDate.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    }
```

but i am not getting proper circle.see: 
[image]

and the shape of circle get changed when i change the size of `UICollectionViewCell` from StoryBoard.

the `lable` having 1:1 aspect ration constraint.

What can i do for proper circle??

Thanks!!

Comment: set cliptoBounds = true for your label

Comment: thats not worked...already checked before. @Anbu.karthik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set it inside

```
func layoutSubviews()
{
    super.layoutSubviews()
    lblDate.layer.cornerRadius = lblDate.frame.width/2
    lblDate.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Comment: Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, When we accessing labels frame before it properly finish layouting, we got wrong Frame.

**Solution:**

You could override `layoutSubviews` method of your `UICollectionView` class.

```
func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    lblDate.layer.cornerRadius = lblDate.frame.width/2
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Also you can create global func:

```
extension UILabel {
func setRoundEdge() {
   let radius = self.frame.height/2
    self.layer.borderWidth = 0.3
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

}

Comment: actually, its not about how to apply the code. Both codes are same. You just applied with the help of extension. And it won't make change in this case.